# How can I link AVA and Cypress tests together for a complete end-to-end test?

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress, end-to-end, ava

I have an AVA test that does a bunch of back-end setup, and at the end of the tests sets a value that I need for my front-end tests, which are written in Cypress.

`1. How can I share that variable between the two tests (they are in separate files)
2. How can I invoke them sequentially, so that I only have to run one command (can I invoke the Cypress tests at the end of my AVA test? Maybe a powershell script?)`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know anything about AVA, but I would guess you could write whatever info you need in a file at the end, then read that in cypress before running your tests.  As for running them sequentially, you can use a makefile command, or maybe an npm command in your package.json file

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do the values of the variables stay in memory even after the first javascript file has ended? That part confuses me, it seems like they would all be reset unless you somehow invoked the cypress tests at the end of the file.

Comment: Ah, I just realized that you said to read it into a file. I see what you mean now. That is definitely possible, although It would be best to avoid that if possible.

Comment: If you don't want to do that, you could store the value in an environment variable, assuming it's just a simple value, and not some complex data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I'll look into environment variables.